# Sum of all perfect square factors of a number

Tags: combinatorics

What is the sum of all the perfect square factors of $810,000$?
It can be rewritten as $2^43^45^4$, but where do I go from here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply start listing perfect squares you can build using some or all of the factors: $2^43^45^4$.

This gives: 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 81, 100, 144, 225, 324, 400, 625, 900, 1296, 2025, 2500, 3600, 5625, 8100, 10000, 22500, 32400, 50625, 90000, 202500, 810000.

Adding gives: 1244061.

Comment: But there are $3\times 3\times 3=27$ perfect square factors, because each of the three exponents can be $0,2,$ or $4$. (The first one you missed is $144$.)

Comment: The sum is correct. I just was lazy with my copy and paste in the first part.

Answer (score 0):

So, we need $$\prod_{r=2,3,5}(1+r^2+r^4)$$

Comment: Thanks, this makes more sense.
Can you share how you derived that?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function